# Encountering an error when installing a package in Julia

Tags: git, julia

Using Windows XP(sp3) and Julia 0.3.3, I encountered the following error when attempting to perform a package installation:

```
julia> Pkg.add("Images")
INFO: Initializing package repository C:\emacs\.julia\v0.3
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
INFO: Cloning cache of BinDeps from git://github.com/JuliaLang/BinDeps.jl.git
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
ERROR: chmod: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
 in wait at task.jl:51
 in sync_end at task.jl:311
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:319
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:71
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in cd at file.jl:30
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in add at pkg.jl:20

julia>
```

I am extremely new to both Git and Julia, so any constructive assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [`git://` protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-Git-Protocol) (which uses the port 9418) is somehow not working (maybe 9418 is blocked), you could switch to https.

From "[Julia: Adding/Removing packages](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#adding-and-removing-packages)":

> Because the package manager uses git internally to manage the package git repositories, users may run into protocol issues (if behind a firewall, for example), when running `Pkg.add`.
>   The following command can be run from the command line to tell git to use ‘https’ instead of the ‘git’ protocol when cloning repositories:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```